# Log level model - do I exponentiate all coefficients for interpretation?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, lognormal-distribution

I'm working with a regression model where I have a log transformed target variable due to the distribution of the log transformation being more normal.

I have some numeric variables and also some expressed as percentages in terms of fractions 0.25 = 25% etc.

Having done some research on how to interpret coefficients of such a model I found this article on towards data science blog:
https://towardsdatascience.com/interpreting-the-coefficients-of-linear-regression-cc31d4c6f235

Under the section on how to interpret the coefficients where there is a log transformed target variable, the following points are made:

> The principles are again similar to the level-level model when it comes to interpreting categorical/numeric variables. Analogically to the intercept, we need to take the exponent of the coefficient: exp(b) = exp(0.01) = 1.01. This means that a unit increase in x causes a 1% increase in average (geometric) y, all other variables held constant.
>
> Two things worth mentioning here:
>
> There is a rule of thumb when it comes to interpreting coefficients of such a model. If abs(b) < 0.15 it is quite safe to say that when b = 0.1 we will observe a 10% increase in y for a unit change in x. For coefficients with larger absolute value, it is recommended to calculate the exponent.
>
> When dealing with variables in [0, 1] range (like a percentage) it is more convenient for interpretation to first multiply the variable by 100 and then fit the model. This way the interpretation is more intuitive, as we increase the variable by 1 percentage point instead of 100 percentage points (from 0 to 1 immediately).

I'd just like to validate those points because I'm going to use them to inform my understanding of the model.

Regarding the first point, is there anything wrong with just exponentiation of all of my coefficients for simplicity? I'd prefer a simple approach rather than a if_else statement along the lines:

```
broom::tidy(my_model$finalModel) %>% # $finalModel since I used caret
  mutate(transformed_estimate = if_else(estimate <= 0.15, estimate, exp(estimate) - 1))
```

Or, is there anything actually wrong with just

```
broom::tidy(my_model$finalModel) %>% 
  mutate(transformed_estimate = exp(estimate) - 1)
```

Next question. Regarding the tip on percentages. I did have input variables expressed as a fraction to denote percentages e.g. 0.1 for 10%, 0.07 for 7% etc. Since reading this article I multiplied all of those by 100 and re-fit the model. Now that I've done that, do I still exponentiate the coefficient or do I leave as is?

Comment: That blog post is extremely misleading because it is never correct to exponentiate the coefficient.  For the right way to interpret linear regression coefficients, please consult our [related posts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=interpret+log+regression+score%3A5).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm glad I posted here first

Comment: One follow up though, on the interpretation of percentage inputs on log level output. if I have an input variable 'apples' that is a value between 0 and 100 representing a percentage, and if I have  coefficient for that variable of 0.016380213, could I interpret that as 'for each percentage increase in apples, target variable can be expected to increase by 0.0163%?

Comment: Take a look at [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8122/822f7cf289e39a999f1bf276c85b8fbc7987.pdf) by David Giles.